# Destructuring a subset of an object directly into a new object

Tags: ecmascript-6

Is there a one-liner to do this that I'm blanking on?

```
// this.state is a basic object with many keys
var {toDate, fromDate, location, flavor} = this.state
var goodKeys = {toDate, fromDate, location, flavor}
// goodKeys is an object that contains a subset of this.state's keys
```

The only way I can think of is:

```
var {keyIDontWant, otherUnwanted, ...goodKeys} = this.state
```

But this seems like it would be confusing to people reading the code, and take more effort to figure out how to write.

Comment: The question is tagged with `ecmascript-6`, object rest spread isn't a part of ES6 and isn't standardized yet. Omitting known 'bad' keys with `{keyIDontWant, otherUnwanted, ...goodKeys}` doesn't make the rest of the keys 'good'.

Comment: This has been asked a number of times. The answer is NO.

Comment: The state of the art is still `goodKeys = {toDate: this.state.toDate, ...};`.

Answer (score 1):

[`_.pick`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.pick) is still one of Underscore/Lodash features that have their use cases in ES6.

ES6 one-liner may be an IIFE and will result in enumerating the list of properties twice:

```
let goodKeys = (
  ({toDate, fromDate, location, flavor}) => ({toDate, fromDate, location, flavor})
)(this.state);
```

ES.next one-liner counterpart to `_.pick` may involve [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
Object.entries(o)
.filter(([key]) => ['toDate', 'fromDate', 'location', 'flavor'].includes(key))
.reduce((obj, [key, val]) => Object.assign(obj, { [key]: val }), {});
```

Comment: Although the ES6 one-liner is admittedly awkward, and makes one desperately wish for a language feature such as [extended dot notation](https://github.com/rtm/js-pick-notation/blob/master/minimal/spec.md), at least in a typed environment it is type-checkable, unlike `_.pick` or roll-your own variants thereof, which involve passing around property names as strings.